# Use config file for my shell script

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I need to create a config file for my own script:
Here is an example:

script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/myuser/test/config
echo "Name=$nam" >&2
echo "Surname=$sur" >&2
```

Content of `/home/myuser/test/config`:

```
nam="Mark"
sur="Brown"
```

that works!

**My question:** is this the correct way to do this or there're other ways?

Comment: The variables should be at the top. I'm surprised it works. Anyway, why do you need a config file? Are you planning to use these variables somewhere else?

Comment: Faheem, I need the variables because my script has many options: using a config file will semplify the script. Thanks

Comment: IMHO its fine. I would do this way.

Comment: `abcde` also does it this way and that is a quite big program (for a shell script). You can have a look at it [here](http://abcde.einval.com).

Comment: @FaheemMitha "why do you need a config file? Are you planning to use these variables somewhere else?"  Why should that shock you?  I've got many scripts on a VM which is used to manage **24**  database servers.  I could have the same parameter validation code in each and every one of those scripts, or I could write **one** set of parameter validation functions, and source them in every other function.

Comment: @FaheemMitha likewise, I've got many functions which need to perform *similar* tasks.  I could write similar code over and over again, or I could write **one** "common functions" script, and source it from all other scripts.

Answer (score 36):

`source` is not secure as it will execute arbitrary code. This may not be a concern for you, but if file permissions are incorrect, it may be possible for an attacker with filesystem access to execute code as a privileged user by injecting code into a config file loaded by an otherwise-secured script such as an init script.

So far, the best solution I've been able to identify is the clumsy reinventing-the-wheel solution:

**myscript.conf**

```
password=bar
echo rm -rf /
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo "Sending your last command $(history 1) to my email"'
hostname=localhost; echo rm -rf /
```

Using `source`, this would run `echo rm -rf /` twice, as well as change the running user's `$PROMPT_COMMAND`. Instead, do this:

**myscript.sh** (Bash 4)

```
#!/bin/bash
typeset -A config # init array
config=( # set default values in config array
    [username]="root"
    [password]=""
    [hostname]="localhost"
)

while read line
do
    if echo $line | grep -F = &>/dev/null
    then
        varname=$(echo "$line" | cut -d '=' -f 1)
        config[$varname]=$(echo "$line" | cut -d '=' -f 2-)
    fi
done < myscript.conf

echo ${config[username]} # should be loaded from defaults
echo ${config[password]} # should be loaded from config file
echo ${config[hostname]} # includes the "injected" code, but it's fine here
echo ${config[PROMPT_COMMAND]} # also respects variables that you may not have
               # been looking for, but they're sandboxed inside the $config array
```

**myscript.sh** (Mac/Bash 3-compatible)

```
#!/bin/bash
config() {
    val=$(grep -E "^$1=" myscript.conf 2>/dev/null || echo "$1=__DEFAULT__" | head -n 1 | cut -d '=' -f 2-)

    if [[ $val == __DEFAULT__ ]]
    then
        case $1 in
            username)
                echo -n "root"
                ;;
            password)
                echo -n ""
                ;;
            hostname)
                echo -n "localhost"
                ;;
        esac
    else
        echo -n $val
    fi
}

echo $(config username) # should be loaded from defaults
echo $(config password) # should be loaded from config file
echo $(config hostname) # includes the "injected" code, but it's fine here
echo $(config PROMPT_COMMAND) # also respects variables that you may not have
               # been looking for, but they're sandboxed inside the $config array
```

Please reply if you find a security exploit in my code.

Comment: FYI this is a Bash version 4.0 solution which sadly is subject to [insane licensing issues](https://blog.bennycornelissen.nl/bash-4-x-on-osx-the-bash-that-apple-wont-ship/) imposed by Apple and is not available by default on Macs

Comment: @Sukima Good point. I've added a version that is compatible with Bash 3. Its weakness is that it will not handle `*` in inputs properly, but then what in Bash handles that character well?

Comment: The first script fails if the password contains a backslash.

Comment: @Kusalananda What if the backslash is escaped? `my\\password`

Comment: This version takes several seconds to process my config file, I found the solution from gw0 to be much faster.

Answer (score 24):

Parse the configuration file, don't execute it.

I'm currently writing an application at work that uses an extremely simple XML configuration:

```xml
<config>
    <username>username-or-email</username>
    <password>the-password</password>
</config>
```

In the shell script (the "application"), this is what I do to get at the username (more or less, I've put it in a shell function):

```bsh
username=$( xmlstarlet sel -t -v '/config/username' "$config_file" )
```

The `xmlstarlet` command is [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/), which is available for most Unices. On some systems, it's installed as `xml`.

I'm using XML since other parts of the application also deals with data encoded in XML files, so it was easiest.

If you prefer JSON, there's [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) which is an easy to use shell JSON parser.

My configuration file would look something like this in JSON:

```json
{                                 
  "username": "username-or-email",
  "password": "the-password"      
}
```

And then I'd be getting the username in the script:

```bsh
username=$( jq -r .username "$config_file" )
```

There is also TOML (["Tom's Obvious Minimal Language"](https://toml.io/en/)), with parsers for several languages. My personal favorite parser, `tomlq`, is part of the `yq` distribution from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/ (uses `jq` behind the scenes).

The TOML version of your configuration file would look like

```
username = "username-or-email"
password = "the-password"
```

(the strings would be JSON-encoded)... and getting data out from it would be as simple as in the JSON case (since `tomlq` is built on top of `jq`):

```bsh
username=$( tomlq -r .username "$config_file" )
```

Comment: Executing the script has a number of advantages and disadvantages. The main disadvantages are security, if someone can alter the config file then they can execute code, and it is harder to make it idiot proof. The advantages are speed, on a simple test it is more than 10,000 times faster to source a config file than to run pq, and flexibility, anyone who likes monkey patching python will appreciate this.

Comment: @icarus How big configuration files do you usually encounter, and how often do you need to parse them in one session? Notice too that several values may be had out of XML or JSON in one go.

Comment: Usually only a few (1 to 3) values. If you are using `eval` to set multiple values then  you are executing selected parts of the config file :-).

Comment: @icarus I was thinking arrays... No need to `eval` anything. The performance hit of using a standard format with an existing parser (even though it's an external utility) is negligible in comparison to the robustness, the amount of code, the ease of use, and maintainability.

Comment: +1 for "parse the config file, don't execute it"

Comment: @icarus, "than to run pq,". what is pq and how is it run to get config? Thank you!

Comment: @Martian2020 I suspect they mean `jq` or `yq`, the tools I'm using in my answer.

Comment: @Martian2020 Yes, I probably ment jq.

Answer (score 23):

Here is a clean and portable version which is compatible with Bash 3 and up, on both Mac and Linux.

It specifies all defaults in a separate file, to avoid the need for a huge, cluttered, duplicated "defaults" config function in all of your shell scripts. And it lets you choose between reading with or without default fallbacks:

**config.cfg**:

```
myvar=Hello World
```

**config.cfg.defaults**:

```
myvar=Default Value
othervar=Another Variable
```

**config.shlib** (this is a library, so there is no shebang-line):

```
config_read_file() {
    (grep -E "^${2}=" -m 1 "${1}" 2>/dev/null || echo "VAR=__UNDEFINED__") | head -n 1 | cut -d '=' -f 2-;
}

config_get() {
    val="$(config_read_file config.cfg "${1}")";
    if [ "${val}" = "__UNDEFINED__" ]; then
        val="$(config_read_file config.cfg.defaults "${1}")";
    fi
    printf -- "%s" "${val}";
}
```

**test.sh (or any scripts where you want to read config values)**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source config.shlib; # load the config library functions
echo "$(config_get myvar)"; # will be found in user-cfg
printf -- "%s\n" "$(config_get myvar)"; # safer way of echoing!
myvar="$(config_get myvar)"; # how to just read a value without echoing
echo "$(config_get othervar)"; # will fall back to defaults
echo "$(config_get bleh)"; # "__UNDEFINED__" since it isn't set anywhere
```

Explanation of the test script:

- Note that *all* usages of config_get in test.sh are wrapped in double quotes. By wrapping every config_get in double quotes, we ensure that text in the variable value will *never* be misinterpreted as flags. And it ensures that we preserve whitespace properly, such as multiple spaces in a row in the config value.
- And what's that `printf` line? Well, it's something you should be aware of: `echo` is a bad command for printing text that you have no control over. Even if you use double quotes, it will interpret flags. Try setting `myvar` (in `config.cfg`) to `-e` and you will see an empty line, because `echo` will think that it's a flag. But `printf` doesn't have that problem. The `printf --` says "print this, and don't interpret anything as flags", and the `"%s\n"` says "format the output as a string with a trailing newline, and lastly the final parameter is the value for printf to format.
- If you aren't going to be echoing values to the screen, then you'd simply assign them normally, like `myvar="$(config_get myvar)";`. If you're going to print them to the screen, I suggest using printf to be totally safe against any echo-incompatible strings that may be in the user config. But echo is fine if the user-provided variable *isn't* the first character of the string you are echoing, since that's the only situation where "flags" could be interpreted, so something like `echo "foo: $(config_get myvar)";` is safe, since the "foo" doesn't begin with a dash and therefore tells echo that the rest of the string isn't flags for it either. :-)

Comment: @user2993656 Thanks for spotting that my original code still had my private config filename (environment.cfg) in it instead of the correct one. As for the "echo -n" edit you did, that depends on the shell used. On Mac/Linux Bash, "echo -n" means "echo without trailing newline", which I did to avoid trailing newlines. But it seems to work exactly the same without it, so thanks for the edits!

Comment: Actually, I just went through and rewrote it to use printf instead of echo, which ensures that we'll get rid of the risk of echo misinterpreting "flags" in the config values.

Comment: I really like this version. I dropped the `config.cfg.defaults` in lieu of defining them at the time of calling `$(config_get var_name "default_value")`. https://tritarget.org/static/Bash%2520script%2520configuration%2520file%2520format.html

Comment: Likewise - this is great.

Answer (score 7):

Most users, although not many containers, already have the `git` binary. Why not therefore use [**`git config`**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) for application configuration management using a dedicated non-conflicting configuration file as in the examples below?

```
# Set
$ git config -f ~/.myapp core.mykey myval

# Get
$ git config -f ~/.myapp core.mykey
myval

# Get invalid
$ git config -f ~/.myapp core.mykey
$ echo $?
1

# List
git config -f ~/.myapp -l
core.mykey=myval

# View
$ cat ~/.myapp 
[core]
    mykey = myval
```

For additional commands, see its man page. It is wise to first ensure the configuration file exists:

```
touch -a ~/.myapp
```

Answer (score 6):

I use this in my scripts:

```
sed_escape() {
  sed -e 's/[]\/$*.^[]/\\&/g'
}

cfg_write() { # path, key, value
  cfg_delete "$1" "$2"
  echo "$2=$3" >> "$1"
}

cfg_read() { # path, key -> value
  test -f "$1" && grep "^$(echo "$2" | sed_escape)=" "$1" | sed "s/^$(echo "$2" | sed_escape)=//" | tail -1
}

cfg_delete() { # path, key
  test -f "$1" && sed -i "/^$(echo $2 | sed_escape).*$/d" "$1"
}

cfg_haskey() { # path, key
  test -f "$1" && grep "^$(echo "$2" | sed_escape)=" "$1" > /dev/null
}
```

Should support every character combination, except keys can't have `=` in them, since that's the separator. Anything else works.

```
% cfg_write test.conf mykey myvalue
% cfg_read test.conf mykey
myvalue
% cfg_delete test.conf mykey
% cfg_haskey test.conf mykey || echo "It's not here anymore"
It's not here anymore
```

Also, this is completely safe since it doesn't use `source` or `eval`.

Comment: Isn't this supposed to first create the config file if it doesn't exist? It doesn't, but `touch -a "${path}"` will of course ensure it exists, also without frivolously updating its mtime.

Comment: Do you have to put the same code in every script?

Answer (score 5):

The most common, efficient and correct way is to use `source`, or `.` as a shorthand form. For example:

```
source /home/myuser/test/config
```

or

```
. /home/myuser/test/config
```

Something to consider, however, is the security issues that using an additional externally-sourced configuration file can raise, given that additional code can be inserted. For more information, including on how to detect and resolve this issue, I would recommend taking a look at the 'Secure it' section of http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/conffile#secure_it

Comment: I had high hopes for that article (came up in my search results too), but the author's suggestion of attempting to use regex to filter out malicious code is an exercise in futility.

Comment: The procedure with dot, requires an absolute path? With the relative one it doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

This is succinct and secure:

```
# Read common vars from common.vars
# the incantation here ensures (by env) that only key=value pairs are present
# then declare-ing the result puts those vars in our environment 
declare $(env -i `cat common.vars`)
```

The `-i` ensures you only get the variables from `common.vars`

Update: 
An illustration of the security is that

```
env -i 'touch evil1 foo=omg boo=$(touch evil2)'
```

Will not produce any touched files. Tested on mac with bash, i.e. using bsd env.

Comment: Just see how evil1 and evil2 files are created if you put this to common.vars

```
touch evil1
foo=omg
boo=$(touch evil2)
```

Comment: @pihentagy For me the following produces no touched files `env -i 'touch evil1 foo=omg boo=$(touch evil2)'`. Running on mac.

Comment: indeed, but cannot access foo. I've tried `env -i ... myscript.sh` and inside that script foo is not defined. However, if you remove "garbage", it will work. So thanks for explaining. :+1:

Comment: An elegant idea, but unfortunately I have seen it choke on comment lines in the config file: `env: ‘#’: No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 2):

This one seems safe and short. Feel free to crack this ruthlessly. I'd like to know of a better way.

## TL;DR;

```
while read LINE; do declare "$LINE"; done < evil.conf
```

I'm using bash 4.3.48.

It's also compliant with `bash --posix`. See bottom for test.

But `sh` doesn't support it because of `declare`.

---

## Basic test for those who want proof

Create file evil.conf

```bsh
echo > evil.conf '
A=1
B=2
C=$(echo hello)

# Could produce side-effect
D=`touch evil`
C=$((1+2))
E=$(ping 8.8.8.8 -n 3)
echo hello

# Could produce visible side-effect
touch evil2
ping 8.8.8.8 -n 3
F=ok'
```

Load the config with the snippet

```bsh
while read LINE; do declare "$LINE"; done < evil.conf
```

Output (see sanitizer in action)

> ```
> bash: declare: `': not a valid identifier
> bash: declare: `': not a valid identifier
> bash: declare: `# Could produce side-effect': not a valid identifier
> bash: declare: `echo hello': not a valid identifier
> bash: declare: `': not a valid identifier
> bash: declare: `# Could produce visible side-effect': not a valid identifier
> bash: declare: `touch evil2': not a valid identifier
> bash: declare: `ping 8.8.8.8 -n 3': not a valid identifier
> ```

Let's check values now

```bsh
for V in A B C D E F; do declare -p $V; done
```

> ```
> declare -- A="1"
> declare -- B="2"
> declare -- C="\$((1+2))"
> declare -- D="\`touch evil\`"
> declare -- E="\$(ping 8.8.8.8 -n 3)"
> declare -- F="ok"
> ```

Check side effects (no side effects):

```bsh
ls evil evil2
```

> ```
> ls: cannot access 'evil': No such file or directory
> ls: cannot access 'evil2': No such file or directory
> ```

Appendix. Test `bash --posix`

```
bash -c 'while read LINE; do declare "$LINE"; done < evil.conf; for V in A B C D E F; do declare -p $V; done' --posix
```

Comment: I redirect the error messages to dev/null. That way I can enter remarks in my config file.  while read LINE; do declare "$LINE" 2>/dev/null; done < evil.conf

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party here, but a simple way of reading env-style files as configuration for a script while preventing execution of arbitrary and potentially malicious code (that the *source* approach is vulnerable to) is to combine the *envsubst* utility, which only substitutes variables and not processes, with the *export* command, which only allows assignment to environment variables and not execution of arbitrary code. A configuration file can therefore be loaded in a `source /path/to/config.env`-fashion with the following one-liner:

```bash
eval export $(envsubst < /path/to/config.env \      # Substitute only variables, not processes
| grep --perl-regexp --invert-match '^\s*(#|$)' \   # Ignore comments and empty lines
| xargs --delimiter '\n' printf " %q")              # Escape and concat strings
```

(**Note**: the placement of comments in the above snippet is not valid bash; they must be removed for correct execution.)

For example:

```bash
# ==== File /path/to/config.env ==== #

# This comment and the following blank line are ignored

TEST1=abc
TEST2="Sweet ${HOME}"
TEST3=$(echo malicious!)

# The following command would produce a parse error:
# ./script.sh: line 6: export: `touch malicious': not a valid identifier
#touch malicious
```

```bash
# ==== File ./script.sh ==== #

#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail

function load_config {
    eval export $(envsubst < "$1" \
    | grep -Pv '^\s*(#|$)' \
    | xargs -d '\n' printf " %q")
}

load_config /path/to/config.env
env | grep TEST
```

```bash
# ==== Terminal ==== #

$ ./script.sh /path/to/config.env
TEST3=$(echo malicious!)
TEST2="Sweet /home/me"
TEST1=abc
```

**ADDENDUM #1:**

**Caveats:** The *envsubst* utility is not syntax-aware — something I had initially overlooked — and will substitute all occurrences of substitution-looking strings anywhere in the config file, such as `${USER}=xyz` (normally invalid variable assignment) and `TEST='Sweet ${HOME}'` (normally not substituted). Furthermore, it will invariably substitute undefined identifiers with empty strings, and it does not recognize conditional substitutions (such as `${VAR:-val}`) and Bash associative arrays (e.g. `${VAR[KEY]}`). All these are not necessarily problems, depending on the use case, but limitations to keep in mind.

**ADDENDUM #2:**

This variant on the previous form exports variables one by one, allowing definitions lower in the configuration file to be aware of previously defined variables:

```bash
while read -r LINE; do
    eval export $(envsubst <<< "$LINE" | xargs --delimiter '\n' printf "%q")
done < <(grep --perl-regexp --invert-match '^\s*(#|$)' /path/to/config.env)
```

Answer (score 1):

I filter for lines that look like an expected parameter definition, then use export to bring them in (other variable-defining keywords don't seem to work with this method, unfortunately).

```
# Define the full set of parameters that we will read from the config file
params="BASENAME SOURCE SHORT_LIFE LONG_LIFE LONG_FREQ TS_FORMAT INDEX_FILE COUNTER_FILE"

# Load in the profile (loop through all possible legal params)
for p in $params
do
        export "`grep ^$p= $config || echo $p=`"
done
```

Ignores all lines that don't match what it's looking for, is compact, easily extended and (I think) secure against malicious config files.

Config file looks like this:

```
BASENAME=foo
SOURCE=bar
this is a comment
# this is also a comment
BASENAME this will be ignored because there`s no = sign
 BASENAME= this will be ignored too (line doesn`t start with param name)
...
COUNTER_FILE=baz
```

Answer (score 0):

For my scenario, `source` or `.` was fine, but I wanted to support local environment variables (ie, `FOO=bar myscript.sh`) taking precedence over configured variables. I also wanted the config file to be user editable and comfortable to someone used to sourced config files, and to keep it as small/simple as possible, to not distract from the main thrust of my very small script.

This is what I came up with:

```
CONF=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-~/config}/myscript.sh
if [ ! -f $CONF ]; then
    cat > $CONF << CONF
VAR1="default value"
CONF
fi
. <(sed 's/^\([^=]\+\) *= *\(.*\)$/\1=${\1:-\2}/' < $CONF)
```

Essentially - it checks for variable definitions (without being very flexible about whitespace) and rewrites those lines so that the value is converted to a default for that variable, and the variable is unmodified if found, like the `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` variable above. It sources this altered version of the config file and continues on.

Future work could make the `sed` script more robust, filter out lines that look weird or aren't definitions, etc, not break on end of line comments - but this is good enough for me for now.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [this article](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/conffile#secure_it) mentioned [here in this response](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175648/use-config-file-for-my-shell-script#answer-175738) I came up with my own solution.

The idea is the same, make a filtered copy of the config file in /tmp and use this one instead of the original.

In addition, emty lines will be ignored and leading spaces will be removed.

**Original config file with malicious code in it:**

```
# Comments are allowed
TEXT_WITH_SINGLE_QUOTES='hello'
TEXT_WITH_DOUBLE_QUOTES="world"

INTEGER_VALUE=2357
DECIMAL_VALUE=0.0011
    SPACES_BEFORE='will be removed'

    # Examples with malicious code
MALICIOUS_EXAMPLE_1='var1' ; echo 'foo'
MALICIOUS_EXAMPLE_2='var2' & echo 'bar'

MALICIOUS_EXAMPLE_3='var3' && echo 'fuu'
```

**The code to filter the input file:**

```
CONFIG='./my.conf'
CONFIG_SECURED='/tmp/my.conf'

rm -f $CONFIG_SECURED

while IFS= read -r line; do
  echo $(sed -E "s/^(\s)?+(#.+$|[a-zA-Z0-9_]+=['\"]?[a-zA-Z0-9_~\.\`-]+['\"]).+$/\2/g" <<< $line) >> $CONFIG_SECURED
  CONFIG=$CONFIG_SECURED
done <<EOF
`cat $CONFIG | grep -v "^$"`
EOF

. $CONFIG
```

**The filtered config file without malicious code in it:**

```
# Comments are allowed
TEXT_WITH_SINGLE_QUOTES='hello'
TEXT_WITH_DOUBLE_QUOTES="world"
INTEGER_VALUE=2357
DECIMAL_VALUE=0.0011
SPACES_BEFORE='will be removed'
# Examples with malicious code
MALICIOUS_EXAMPLE_1='var1'
MALICIOUS_EXAMPLE_2='var2'
MALICIOUS_EXAMPLE_3='var3'
```

The filtering part is certainly perfectible, but it think it does most of the important stuff.

Answer (score 0):

my favourite approach is to use [crudini](https://www.pixelbeat.org/programs/crudini/)

on Ubuntu you can install it with `sudo apt install crudini`

example:

```
$ crudini --set example.ini "section name" "value name" 'malicious; echo $HOME'
$ cat example.ini 
[section name]
value name = malicious; echo $HOME
$ value_name=$(crudini --get example.ini "section name" "value name")
$ echo "$value_name"
malicious; echo $HOME
$
```